# Algebra in Cantelli-Cheybyshev Inequality Proof

Tags: mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

I am confused by the following (possibly simple) algebra in the proof of the Cantelli-Cheybyshev inequality. I am following Rohatgi and Saleh (2015, Section 3.4 Lemma 1) where we plug in $\phi(x)=(x+c)^2$ into Markov's inequality to get:
\begin{equation}
P(Y \geq t) \leq P\big( \phi(Y) \geq (t+c)^2 \big) \leq \underbrace{\frac{{E}[(Y+c)^2]}{(t+c)^2}}_{RHS}
\end{equation} 
where $EY=0, t\geq 1,$ and $c>0$. To find the tightest bound, we minimize the RHS wrt to $c$. This gives us
\begin{equation}
c^* = \frac{Var Y}{t}
\end{equation} 
The proof in Rohatgi and Saleh (2015) and elsewhere (e.g. [Cantelli's inequality proof](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113972/cantellis-inequality-proof)) says plugging in $c^*$ gives the desired expression:
\begin{equation}
P(Y \geq t) \leq \frac{Var Y}{Var Y + t^2}
\end{equation}
But the algebra in between doesn't seem trivial (at least to me): if I plug in $c^*$ into RHS, I don't see how to get the RHS of Cantelli's inequality even knowing that I can add or substract $EY=0$:
\begin{equation} 
\frac{{E}[(Y+c)^2]}{(t+c)^2}\bigg|_{c=c^*} = \frac{Var Y + (Var Y/t)^2}{t^2 + 2t(Var Y/t) + (Var Y/t)^2} = ...?
\end{equation}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that, factorizing the polynomial:

$$t^2 + 2t(Var Y/t) + (Var Y/t)^2=(t+Var Y/t)^2=\frac{1}{t²}(t²+Var Y)^2$$