# Proof of inequality $P(X \geq \lambda) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + \lambda^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, measure-theory

Hello I have the assumptions that $E(X) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X) = {\sigma}^{2}$ . Why does this inequality hold $P(X \geq \lambda) \leq \frac{{\sigma}^{2}}{{\sigma}^{2} + {\lambda}^{2}}$ for $ \lambda \geq 0$.
It seems like a stronger statement than the Markov inequality and I assume therefore that it must have something to do with the fact that the expectation of $X$ is 0.

Comment: hmm, well for starters, Markov applies to nonnegative random variables, and nonnegative variables with zero expectation are rather boring...

Comment: You are right , I totally forgot about that

Comment: The statement that $X^2\ge\lambda^2$ is equivalent to $\{ X\ge\lambda \text{ or } X\le -\lambda\},$ so $\Pr(X \ge \lambda) \le \Pr(X^2 \ge\lambda^2),$ and since $\operatorname E(X^2)=\sigma^2,$ Markov's inequality applied to $X^2$ yields $$ \Pr(X\ge\lambda) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{\lambda^2}. $$ (I don't know whether that serves as a starting point for this or not.)

Comment: The expectation of $X$ is irrelevant, provided it's finite, because $\Pr(X \ge \lambda)=\Pr(X-\mu\ge\lambda-\mu)$ for any finite number $\mu.$ Using $\mu=E[X]$ puts this into the form of the question.  Similarly, without any loss of generality you could assume $\sigma^2=1$ by rescaling $X$ and $\lambda.$

Comment: This is sometimes called the _one-sided_ Chebyshev Inequality or the Chebyshev-Cantelli Inequality. See the latter half of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19101/6633) on stats.SE.  More generally, for _even_ positive integer $n$, $$\mathbf 1_{[a,\infty)}\leq \left(\frac{x+b}{a+b}\right)^n$$ and so $$P\{X \geq a\} \leq E\left[\left(\frac{X+b}{a+b}\right)^n\right] 
= (a+b)^{-n}E[(X+b)^n]$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This inequality is called *Cantelli's inequality* (*Probability and Measure* by Patrick Billingsley, Exercise 5.5).  To prove it, note that for $x > 0$, $\{X \geq \lambda\} \subseteq \{(X + x)^2 \geq (\lambda + x)^2\}$, hence it follows by Markov's inequality that
\begin{align}
P(X \geq \lambda) \leq P((X + x)^2 \geq (\lambda + x)^2) \leq \frac{E[(X + x)^2]}{(\lambda + x)^2} = \frac{\sigma^2 + x^2}{(\lambda + x)^2}. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Observe that (i.e., "completing the squares"):
\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma^2 + x^2}{(\lambda + x)^2} = 
(\lambda^2 + \sigma^2)\left[\frac{1}{\lambda + x} - \frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2 + \sigma^2}\right]^2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + \lambda^2},
\end{align}
whence
\begin{align}
\min_{x > 0}\frac{\sigma^2 + x^2}{(\lambda + x)^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + \lambda^2}. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives:
\begin{align}
P(X \geq \lambda) \leq \min_{x > 0}\frac{\sigma^2 + x^2}{(\lambda + x)^2}
= \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + \lambda^2}.
\end{align}

---

For a general random variable $X$ with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$, the inequality becomes (simply note $X - m$ has mean $0$ and use the inequality proved for the zero mean case):
\begin{align}
P(X - m \geq \lambda) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + \lambda^2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

When $E[X=0]$ then the variance is

$$\sigma^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 f(x) dx$$

We can consider some parts of this integral seperately. Consider the area 1 and area 2 in the image below.

[image: split up]

$$\sigma^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 f(x) dx \geq \underbrace{ \int_{-\infty}^0 x^2 f(x) dx}_{\text{contribution from area 2}} +  \underbrace{ \int_{\lambda}^\infty x^2 f(x) dx}_{\text{contribution from area 1}}$$

The part from area 1

$$\int_{\lambda}^\infty x^2 f(x) dx \geq \int_{\lambda}^\infty \lambda^2 f(x) dx = \lambda^2 P(X\geq \lambda)$$

The part from area 2

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 x^2 f(x) dx \geq \mu_{X < 0}^2 P(X < 0) \geq \lambda^2 \frac{P(X \geq \lambda)^2}{1-P(X \geq \lambda)}$$

Where $\mu_{X<0}$ is the mean of the part below 0.

- The first inequality for area 2 follows from $E[X^2] = \sigma^2 + \mu^2 \geq  \mu^2$, the relationship between the raw moment and the mean.
- The second inequality for area 2 follows from the fact that $\mu_{X<0}$ must equal the part above 0. $$\mu_{X < 0} P(X < 0) + \mu_{X > 0} P(X > 0) = E[X] = 0$$ and we can relate this to the probability mass for $X \geq \lambda$ $$-\mu_{X<0} = \frac{\mu_{X > 0} P(X > 0)}{P(X < 0)} \geq \frac{\lambda P(X\geq \lambda)}{P(X < 0)} \geq \frac{\lambda P(X\geq \lambda)}{1-P(X \geq \lambda)}$$

From the inequalities with the two parts it follows that

$$\sigma^2 \geq \lambda^2 P(X\geq \lambda) + \lambda^2 \frac{P(X \geq \lambda)^2}{1-P(X \geq \lambda)} = \frac{\lambda^2}{P(X \geq \lambda)^{-1}-1}$$

and

$$ P(X\geq \lambda) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+\lambda^2}$$

The equality occurs for a discrete distribution that concentrates a mass $P(X\geq \lambda)$ in the point $\lambda$ and a mass $1-P(X\geq \lambda)$ in the point $\mu_{X<0} = \lambda \frac{P(X\geq \lambda)}{1-P(X\geq \lambda)}$